# Как в modx revo отсортировать чанки в шаблоне?

Tags: modx, revo

Вот к примеру есть у нас шаблон с выводом чанков:

```
[[$banner]]
[[$service]]
[[$news]]
```

и т.д.

Как мне с помощью дополнительных полей отсортировать его? (чтобы можно было редактировать позицию чанка). Буду очень признателен за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Например воспользоваться компонентом [MIGX](https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/migx).

Создать `tv` например с именем `chunks` и типом ввода `migx`

*Вкладки формы примерно так:*

```
[{"caption":"Секции", "fields": [
    {"field":"chunk","caption":"Чанк"}
  ]
}]
```

*Разметка колонок:*

```
[{
  "header": "Чанк", "sortable": "true", "dataIndex": "chunk"
}]
```

В итоге, можно будет добавлять через это поле нужные чанки и сортировать их "перетаскиванием" в нужном порядке.

В шаблоне соответственно выводить с помощью `getImageList`:

```
[[getImageList? &tvname=`chunks` &tpl=`@CODE:[[+chunk]]`]]
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Как до этого не додумался)

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю к ответу выше.

Сделал благодаря Александру. У меня в доп полях настраиваются чанки и вывожу их так

```
[[getImageList?
        &tvname=`chunks`
        &tpl=`@FIELD:tpl`
    ]]
```

Вкладки формы задаю так:

```
[{"caption":"Блоки",
 "fields": [{
  "field": "tpl",
  "caption": "Дополнительное поле",
  "inputTVtype": "listbox",
  "inputOptionValues":
    "Обложка==hero_img||
    Разделы с картинкой==sec_with_img||
    Текст в раскрывающихся карточках==hideable_panels||
    Причины новые==reasons_new||
    Причины с разделителем==reasons_hr||
    Причины с иконкой==reasons_ico||
    Шаги==steps||
    Причины с номером==reasons_num||
    Причины с иконкой справа==reasons_ico_right||
    Причины с большой картинкой==reasons_big_img||
    Содержимое==serviceContent||
    Дополнительные услуги==similarServices"
  }]
}]
```

Теперь клиент для каждой новой страницы, использующей шаблон настраивает порядок вывода блоков как хочет)
Осталось только определить чанки перечисленные в `inputOptionValues`.